# Install Shield 2009 Premier : Don't want to put the entry to control panel

Tags: registry, installshield, admin, controlpanel, privilege

My installation would
1. copy some files
2. some registry entries that require admin privilege e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\MyRegistry

What I want:
1. No entry to the control panel and yes i don't need an uninstallation.

Question may arise, why I don't do it manually? Only for the admin privileged registry entries[Is there any way to do it without install shield ?]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this MSI property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367750(VS.85).aspx). All you need to do is to set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367519(VS.85).aspx).  What you need to do is:

> You can omit registering an
>   application by removing the
>   RegisterProduct Action, RegisterUser
>   Action, PublishProduct Action, and
>   PublishFeatures Action from the
>   InstallExecuteSequence Table and
>   AdvtExecuteSequence Table. All of
>   these actions must be removed, or some
>   trace of the application may remain in
>   the registry. Removing all of these
>   actions prevents the application from
>   being listed in the Add or Remove
>   Programs feature in Control Panel, and
>   prevents the advertisement of the
>   application. Removing all of these
>   actions also prevents the application
>   from being registered with the Windows
>   Installer configuration data. This
>   means that you cannot remove, repair,
>   or reinstall the application by using
>   the Windows Installer Command-Line
>   Options, or the Windows Installer
>   application programming interface
>   (API).